# JavaScript keyup handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I'm building a GIF animation based movement system for my game.

The question is, once the keycode (lets say 37) is down, how do I detect if/when that certain key is up?

I want to move the charater and play the GIF while the key is down, but I need to stop the animation and stop the character from moving when the key is up.

Comment: Assume that any keys that aren't "down" are up - you could start building out a map on each keydown, ex: `var keysDown = {}; //onkeydown keysDown[e.which] = true` then onkeyup, set it to false, and you can then check that map for keycodes of currently pressed buttons

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the `onkeydown` event described here to catch an action: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

Why not use the opposite function to detect when an action should stop? It's called `onkeyup`, and it's described here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp